# Issue installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 3: QFE.cab is corrupt

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Any Ideas? Not finding much in searching...

**Error:**

[image: Here is a screenshot:]

[Here is my Log](https://gist.github.com/ElanHasson/8e3dc0a639e7f6b1fc9a)

Comment: Do you execute the installer as administrator? (Right Click on the installer and then select Run As Administrator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was logging into my MSDN and downloading en_visual_studio_professional_2013_with_update_3_x86_dvd_4836427.iso.

This is the full installer for VS2013 with Update 3 included.

Just reinstall and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem yesterday. No VS2013 Update 3 would install - always failing at KB2829760.

What fixed it for me was a full delete of the contents of folder

`\Users\[YourUsername]\AppData\temp`.

Installation went smoothly right afterwards.